# How to select all values in a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I have an array called markers. I have a Google Map populated with markers and I want to call a function that selects all array values so I can set all the marker images to original, before setting the new one to highlighted. This is unless there is a google api way of setting all marker images.

```
 function show(i)
{
   markers[all].setIcon("lib/images/default.png");
   markers[i].setIcon("lib/images/default_h.png");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for(var i in markers)
{
   markers[i].setIcon("lib/images/default.png");
}
```

If your array keys are incremented integers you should do this way instead

```
var size = markers.length;
for(var i=0; i<size; i++) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can to it with the every function:

```
   function show(i) {
        markers.every(function(marker) {
            marker.setIcon("lib/images/default.png");
            return true;
        }

        markers[i].setIcon("lib/images/default_h.png");
    }
```